# Method is not calling from UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, methods, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` and in  `didSelect` method i'm calling method of another class with parameter and when i click the row i want to open that class `xib` with corresponding paramter .But here when i click the `UITableView` row nothing is happening ,actually method is calling but new `xib` is not opening.

following code in `didSelect` method`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SearchResult* hit = (SearchResult*)[results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [epubViewController loadSpine:hit.chapterIndex atPageIndex:hit.pageIndex highlightSearchResult:hit];
}
```

`

epubViewController is the object of second class and  "loadSpine: atPageIndex: highlightSearchResult:" is a method in that class"

please help me

Comment: You just called a method, not presenting it. use pushViewController or presentViewController for doing this

Comment: but the same thing working...in github project AepubReader  .they calling this line and working

Comment: can you post the code of AepubReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not presenting `epubViewController`. Add this line after `loadSpine` method call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: epubViewController animated: YES];
```

Also, I would pass `hit` to `epubViewController` and call `loadSpine` on `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` method inside of `epubViewController`.

Comment: It is better way to pass an object and don't expose epubViewControler's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please push or present your view controller using this method and in `-(void)viewDidLoad:`call the method you want to hit by using this code-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: epubViewController animated: YES];
```

in `viewDidLoad` call your load spine method as

```
[self loadSpine];
```

hope this helps